How to wire two different services, implementing same interface based on environment in symfony 7
I am trying to wire two different Adapter services, which implement the same interface.
But still using when@dev clause dont work in this case
services:
    App\Mocks\Adapter\ExampleAdapterMock: ~
    App\Adapter\ExampleAdapter: ~

    App\Adapter\ExampleAdapterInterface: '@App\Mocks\Adapter\ExampleAdapterMock' ``

when@dev:
    services:
        App\Adapter\ExampleAdapterInterface: '@App\Mocks\Adapter\ExampleAdapterMock'

when@prod: &prod_adapter
    services:
        App\Adapter\ExampleAdapterInterface: '@App\Adapter\ExampleAdapter'

when@qas: *prod_adapter



I don't see why it doesn't work, maybe you can share the error message ?
You can also declare a Factory for you interface, which will return the correct implementation depending on context (arguments, environment, etc.).
App\Adapter\ExampleAdapterInterface:
    factory: '@App\Adapter\ExampleAdapterFactory'
    arguments: ['%kernel.environment%']

